# Fail without paramsSerializer in Axios in Javascript

Tags: axios

I need to apply the encode to the post-request parameters, so I added `encodeURIComponent` into the params values. However, it failed.

```js
axios({
url: "example.com",
method: "POST",
params: { username: encodeURIComponent(CREDENTIALS.username), password: encodeURIComponent(CREDENTIALS.password) },
httpsAgent: new https.Agent({
    cert: certificate,
    key: key,
  }),
})
```

However, it failed.

```
data: { loginStatus: 'CERT_AUTH_REQUIRED' }
```

If I add `paramsSerializer`:

> `paramsSerializer` is an optional function in charge of serializing `params`

```js
paramsSerializer: function (params) {
  return encodeURIComponent(params)
}
```

The request won't have the above error.

I have checked the url in both case are the same from Axios log return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When making a POST request with Axios, sensitive data like usernames and passwords should be sent in the request body (data field), not in params. The params field is for query parameters.

Here's how to send the data correct way:

```
axios({
    url: "example.com",
    method: "POST",
    data: {
    username: encodeURIComponent(CREDENTIALS.username),
    password: encodeURIComponent(CREDENTIALS.password),
    },
    httpsAgent: new https.Agent({
    cert: certificate,
    key: key,
    }),
})
    .then((response) => {

    })
    .catch((error) => {
    });
```